# Adding files into NSMutableArray

Tags: file, nsmutablearray

I would like to on a press of a button to save an xml file into the documents directory and to add that file into an array where this array would later be sent to an email address. I think I have the saving figured out,but how do I put the files into an array? Also is it possible to somehow send these file to an email address? Could anyone give some advice on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *filePath = @"...<path to directory where XML is saved on the device>";

NSMutableArray *mArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

//Repeat this for every file you want to attach
[mArray addObject:filePath];
```

After doing this.. whenever the email with the attachements need to be sent, loop through the array and add it as a attachement.
Use this as a reference. http://iosdevelopertips.com/email/how-to-send-email-with-attachments-example-using-iphone-camera-to-email-a-photo.html

This is for a image, but should work well for any file with some modifications.

Comment: Won't this just add the file path as string and not the actual xml file with its data to the array? As I dont have an email interface I was thinking of HTTP POST or something similar,is it still possible to do it like you mentioned?